# Route53 domain suddenly not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have an aws route53 domain that I registered and assigned to a website.
Everything was working fine and suddenly a few days ago the domain stopped resolving.

When I use 'dig mydomain.com' I notice this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: *****
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            900 IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 14809***** 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 187 msec
;; WHEN: Mon Dec  5 20:39:52 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

But I believe that the AUTHORITY SECTION with aws route53 should be:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.    118928  IN  NS  ns-806.awsdns-36.net.
example.com.    118928  IN  NS  ns-1456.awsdns-54.org.
example.com.    118928  IN  NS  ns-1713.awsdns-22.co.uk.
example.com.    118928  IN  NS  ns-105.awsdns-13.com.
```

I have checked all my route53 hosted zone settings and they are correct
so I don't understand why this suddenly happened and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. Didn't realize I had a typo in my registered email address for the domain and hence never got the registrant verification email which of course led to the domain being suspended. Changing email and verifying resolved issue.